# What should be the speed of Teradata Fastload Utility?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I'm using jdbc FastLoad to load a table of 1 billion rows. The file size is around 300Gb

It's taking me about 10 hours.

I was trying to set different batch size. But ended up with optimal 100000. Each  batch for 100000 rows takes about 3 seconds (SLOW!!!!)

**This doesn't really make sense. Why is it taking so long? Or is it normal? I was expecting a better performance by FastLoad**

Comment: I can load 100000 rows in less than 3 seconds on my laptop using TDExpress. How many sessions did you use?JDBC FastLoad is slower than standalone FastLoad/TPT Load, you should try TPT Load (maybe multiple instances).

Comment: Need to take network speed into account as well.   Set table/multiset table? Does the table have a PI?

Comment: Table has Primary key. INTEGER. set table

Comment: @dnoeth thank you but there is no TPT implementation in JAVA as far as i know

Comment: I use only one session

Comment: @dnoeth "multiple sessions?" could you please provide more details on this? this sounds interesting. Is there any out of box implementation for multi session `jdbc FastLoad`? Thank you

Comment: I don't know about Java FastLoad, but a single session is not enough to keep your system busy. You talk about loading a *file*, then write a simple TPT script and run it from command line.

Comment: FastLoad will be significantly faster loading into a NoPI table.  The # of sessions is just a parameter. [Documentation](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_SESSIONS)

Comment: To the point raised by dnoeth, JDBC FastLoad may not be the most efficient solution to move the data volume at hand. Andrew raised a good point about the network infrastructure between the source and target environments as well as using a NoPI table to stage the data. Have you confirmed the database is only allocating a single session for your FastLoad activity? Teradata Active System Management on certain systems will allocate the number of sessions that can be used for FastLoad.

Comment: I'm using SESSION parameter in `jdbc` connection string. I set it to 16. I think this is the network limitation

Comment: The number of sessions is possibly not controlled by you, but by workload management. When you increase the number of sessions there's a high probability that FastLoad is CPU-bound on the client, as it's single threaded and your Java program probably, too. Using TPT you can easily run multiple LOAD instances (moving the bottleneck to the network).